# is it possible to close child window from parent window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am with stuck an unorthodox requirement, i have opened a window on page load using jquery like this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 loadLifeCare();

        });
```

and the function goes like this

```
function loadLifeCare()
    {
        window.open('/abc/abc/abc','','width=100,height=100');
    }
```

now this function loads a url in the new window which creates a session for the user on different 
domain.
i just need to know **if it is either possible to close this window after few seconds or change the href  and reload it to a different link**,
and i can't code on the child window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will open the window and then close it after 10 seconds...

```
function loadLifeCare()
{
    var wnd = window.open('/abc/abc/abc','','width=100,height=100');
    setTimeout(function() {
        wnd.close();
    }, 10000);
}
```

If you want to redirect it elsewhere, you can do this...

```
function loadLifeCare()
{
    var wnd = window.open('/abc/abc/abc','','width=100,height=100');
    setTimeout(function() {
        wnd.location.href = "http://wherever.com";
    }, 10000);
}
```

Comment: He is opening a window to a different domain, I think this makes the window reference invalid if I am not mistaken.
nm my mistake, just checked, it works, which is a little surprising to me, considering you could redirect to facebook and then after a while change href to a login like page but different url :)

Comment: @PiniH I'm not sure about that.  I think it may only stop him from referencing the DOM, but the window object should be accessible.  I'll try it.

Comment: @Archer thanks a lot,i thought it was not possible as control is passed to different domain but it works like a charm :) .